# Amazon CloudFront and HTTPsL What do I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https

So here's the scoop. Bear with me here, it's been a long day. I've got a domain name, we'll call that **company.com**. Then I have a back-end domain (for shorter URLs and things), we'll call that **compa.ny**. Both have SSL certs through Let's Encrypt, and both are forced to connect through HTTPs.

I use Amazon CloudFront to serve up my media assets because it's faster and cheaper than hosting it on my VPS. So...

I've got a CNAME record for **compa.ny** that is setup with my CloudFront Domain. That's at *cdn*.**compa.ny**. I'm making sure that the CloudFront assets are served up over HTTPs as well. Here's where things get greasy.

When my browser (Chrome) connects to *cdn*.**compa.ny**, it is rereouted to the CloudFront Domain, and the SSL cert that's given is the one owned by *Amazon CloudFront*. The problem is that the browser goes, "Oh, hey! This SSL cert is from CloudFront... but the domain we're connected to *isn't* Amazon CloudFront... Liar!" Thus, my browser doesn't trust the cert and refuses to load any assets over it. I can directly access them, but it warns me that my connection is insecure, etc.

I have no idea what to do.

Thanks for any help you could offer! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your CloudFront distribution is still serving the HTTPS Certificate that is valid only for *.cloudfront.net, it sounds like either:

1. You have not correctly added your CNAME as an alternate domain name for your distribution from within your CloudFront distribution's config.
2. You have not applied your HTTPS certificate to your Distributions config.

Depending on if it works over HTTP, it sounds like it could be the second scenario.

Comment: See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html for clarity, CloudFront needs an SSL cert/key/chain-set uploaded through IAM in order to serve https on the front-end.  The back-end server's cert doesn't propagate out ... it can't, because CloudFront (like any layer 7 solution) decrypts requests and responses so it can process them, and re-encrypts them on The way to the browser and/or origin.